Using SplashScreen API's setKeepOnCondition while selecting default destination
In my MainActivity I need to read some DataStore values in order to decide if I should show the LoginScreen or the Main screen, so I enabled the splashscreen before calling onCreate(). I then use a runBlocking to fetch the values and set the startDestination as you can see below. I would expect the KeepOnScreenCondition to show the splash while the runblocking is setting the destination. However, it still seems to go away early enough where the LoginScreen is shown first (really shortly) and then moves to the main screen (as it should in my case).
What am I missing here? Does this mean that only the LaunchedEffect's block is being blocked?
        var isLoadingDataStoreTokens by remember { mutableStateOf(true) }
        var startDestination : Destination by remember {
            mutableStateOf(
                LoginScreenDestination
            )
        }
        val tokenManager: AuthTokenManager by inject()

        LaunchedEffect(Unit) {
            runBlocking {
                val authToken = tokenManager.getBearerToken().first()
                val isGuest = tokenManager.isGuest().first()
                startDestination =
                    if (authToken != null && isGuest != null) DissertationsScreenDestination else LoginScreenDestination
                isLoadingDataStoreTokens = false
            }
        }

        splashScreen.setKeepOnScreenCondition {
            !isLoadingDataStoreTokens
        }


Use setKeepOnScreenCondition in a launch effect before reading from data store:
        LaunchedEffect(Unit) {
            splashScreen.setKeepOnScreenCondition {
                !isLoadingDataStoreTokens
            }
        }
        LaunchedEffect(Unit) {
            runBlocking {
                val authToken = tokenManager.getBearerToken().first()
                val isGuest = tokenManager.isGuest().first()
                startDestination =
                    if (authToken != null && isGuest != null) DissertationsScreenDestination else LoginScreenDestination
                isLoadingDataStoreTokens = false
            }
        }

        

Update 1:
Let the keep on screen condition store outside compose, like this:
class MainActivity : ComponentActivity() {
    // Splash screen keep on screen condition.
    private var shouldKeepOnScreen = AtomicBoolean(true)

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        val splashScreen = installSplashScreen()
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        enableEdgeToEdge()
        splashScreen.setKeepOnScreenCondition {
            return@setKeepOnScreenCondition shouldKeepOnScreen.get()
        }
        setContent {
            MyApplicationTheme {
                Scaffold(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize()) { innerPadding ->
                    Greeting(
                        name = "Android",
                        modifier = Modifier.padding(innerPadding),
                        shouldKeepOnScreen
                    )
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

@Composable
fun Greeting(name: String, modifier: Modifier = Modifier, shouldKeepOnScreen: AtomicBoolean) {
    val context = LocalContext.current
    LaunchedEffect(Unit) {
        launch {
            // Note the app is showing with splash screen keeps on.
            Toast.makeText(context, "App is showing.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()

            // Simulate reading value from data store.
            delay(5000)
            shouldKeepOnScreen.set(false)

            // Simulate launch to login or main screen.
            Toast.makeText(context, "Launch to login or main screen.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        }
    }
    Text(
        text = "Hello $name!",
        modifier = modifier
    )
}


This creates an infinite loop basically

Ok, see if update 1 is working.
